# Oracle MAF : Is it do anything that IOS xcode and android eclipse does

Tags: java, android, ios, oracle

I am new in Oracle MAF, Is it work well like xcode work for IOS and eclipse work for android development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAF uses a web layer for the UI effectively similar to PhoneGap/Cordova so its not like writing your code in xcode. The app would be an HTML5 app wrapped in an xcode project with the JVM embedded within. As far as I know the embedded JVM uses an interpreter since JIT's are disallowed on iOS.

Disclaimer: I work for [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which does use native code for iOS development in Java thru AOT bytecode to C translation.

Comment: Is Codename one use to develop android app:?

Comment: Android, iOS, Windows etc.

Comment: Wow Thank you It helps me. Can you tell me other plateform that we can implement IOS android, windows app with same logic,
I know Delphi, but it is not open source like java.

Comment: There are MANY but they generally divide into porting tools (like Xamarin) where you need to rewrite native code for every OS or HTML5 code. There aren't many in Java that are open source like Codename One. FYI MAF isn't open source and has a pretty steep license fee for shipping apps.

Comment: Ohh... you mean Codename is not open source

Comment: Codename One is open source. MAF isn't.